Polars map elements doesn't work properly with isinstance
I have a polars dataframe with two columns, one contains lists of string and the other one string. I want to apply the following expression to both columns. However, for some reason isinstance(x, list) doesn't work properly.
def process_column(column_name: str, alias_name: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.col(column_name).map_elements(
            lambda x: " ".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x
        )
        .str.to_lowercase()
        .str.split(by="-")
        .list.join(" ")
        .alias(alias_name)
        )

Here is a sample dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "lists": [["hello", "World"], ["polars", "IS", "fast"]],
    "strings": ["foo-hello", "bOO"]
})

Applying process_column to the "strings" column gives the expected result.
df.with_columns(process_column("strings", "processed_string"))

However, for the "lists" column a SchemaError is raised.
df.with_columns(process_column("lists", "processed_lists"))

polars.exceptions.SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected `String`, got `list[str]`

I tried using map_elements with return_dtype=pl.String. This doesn't return an error, but the output is wrong.

I'd start by checking what is going on when applying pl.Expr.map_elements to a column of type List[pl.String] as follows.
def check(x):
    print(x)
    return x

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("lists").map_elements(check)
)

shape: (2,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "hello"
    "World"
]
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "polars"
    "IS"
    "fast"
]
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ lists                    ┆ strings   │
│ ---                      ┆ ---       │
│ list[str]                ┆ str       │
╞══════════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ ["hello", "World"]       ┆ foo-hello │
│ ["polars", "IS", "fast"] ┆ bOO       │
└──────────────────────────┴───────────┘

This suggests that the function passed to pl.Expr.map_elements doesn't receive native python lists, but pl.Series objects instead. Hence, we should replace
lambda x: " ".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x

with
lambda x: x.str.concat(" ").item() if isinstance(x, pl.Series) else x

to obtain the expected result.
def process_column(column_name: str, alias_name: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.col(column_name)
        .map_elements(
            lambda x: x.str.concat(" ").item() if isinstance(x, pl.Series) else x,
            return_dtype=pl.String
        )
        .str.to_lowercase()
        .str.split(by="-")
        .list.join(" ")
        .alias(alias_name)
    )

df.with_columns(process_column("lists", "processed_lists"))

Note. I've also added the parameter return_dtype=pl.String to silence a warning about calling map_elements without specifying return_dtype possibly leading to unpredictable results.
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────────────────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ lists                    ┆ strings   ┆ processed_lists │
│ ---                      ┆ ---       ┆ ---             │
│ list[str]                ┆ str       ┆ str             │
╞══════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ ["hello", "World"]       ┆ foo-hello ┆ hello world     │
│ ["polars", "IS", "fast"] ┆ bOO       ┆ polars is fast  │
└──────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘

